# how to add two javascript objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

i have problem with javascript objects i want to add two objects structure same 
here they are also first of all they objects is string

```
data1 = '{"display:[{"counter":"A023","token":"001"}]"}'
data2 = '{"display:[{"counter":"A013","token":"003"}]"}'
```

expected result 
new

```
data = '{"display:[{"counter":"A023","token":"001"}, {"counter":"A013","token":"003"}]"}'
```

i have tried these codes

```
var data1 = JSON.parse(data1);
var data1 = JSON.parse(data1);
var newdata = $.merge(data1.display, data2.display);
```

i cant solve this problem, i don't know how to do it I also tried other codes

Comment: Read more about [JavaScript spread syntax](https://codesearchable.com/pt/9593753/). Be sure `object` in `...object` must be an object, including empty object `{}`, otherwise an error will be thrown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```js
let data1 = '{"display":[{"counter":"A023","token":"001"}]}'
let data2 = '{"display":[{"counter":"A013","token":"003"}]}'

data1 = JSON.parse(data1);
data2 = JSON.parse(data2);

data = JSON.stringify({display: [...data1.display, ...data2.display]})
console.log(data)
```

Comment: thanks i move one step but i need it last data should be string

Comment: @NurbekBoymurodov see my edit now. data is now string

Comment: it returns me this {"display":[[{"counter":"205","token":"A021"}],[{"counter":"205","token":"A022"}]]}  i wanted this one {"display":[{"counter":"205","token":"A021"},{"counter":"205","token":"A022"}]}

Comment: console.log removes the outermost \"\". Try running typeof data and you will see it is string

Comment: yes it is string and just compare     {"display":[[{"counter":"205","token":"A021"}],[{"counter":"205","token":"A022"}]]}       and this    {"display":[{"counter":"205","token":"A021"},{"counter":"205","token":"A022"}]}    tere are extra [] between two arrys

Comment: I get this as a result: "{"display":[{"counter":"A023","token":"001"},{"counter":"A013","token":"003"}]}" when I run the code snippet above (press the run code snippet). There are no extra [] since when you use the spread operator on 2 arrays it concats them into a single array

Comment: may be you should use it in chrome console because when i wrote again JSON.parse(newdata) it gave me undefined

Comment: Here, try this: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-nash-e9s7h @NurbekBoymurodov

Comment: @Kaca992 do you have facebook or something like that i can send you pic

Comment: @NurbekBoymurodov can you post your code on codesandbox and send the link here? Also try this: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-nash-e9s7h (I posted the wrong link the first time, sorry)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-lamarr-iif2e          @Kaca992  see line 253 and 257

Comment: When you do this:
             var newdata = JSON.stringify({display:[...data1.display,...data2.display]});
              var newdata1 = JSON.parse(newdata);
It is bacivally the same if you did this:
var newData1 = {display:[...data1.display,...data2.display]};

JSON.stringify and parse are 2 oposite functions (stringify turns a JS object to string, while parse takes a string and turns it into an object).

You need to save newdata into your localstorage (string value), not newdata1

Comment: @Kaca992   ooo thanks it is my mistake now everything is nice

Comment: @NurbekBoymurodov no problem. glad to help

Comment: Kaca992 Hi!! sorry bothering you again i have another problem can you help me with it

Comment: @NurbekBoymurodov sure. post a question and link it here, and if I can will try to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the JSON strings follow a valid format:

```js
let data1 = '{"display":[{"counter":"A023","token":"001"}]}';
let data2 = '{"display":[{"counter":"A013","token":"003"}]}';

let data = {
  display: JSON.parse(data1).display.concat(JSON.parse(data2).display)
};

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to wrap your data objects in quotes. You can notate them as regular objects and then use the spread operation to achieve what you want.

```
let data1 = {"display:[{"counter":"A023","token":"001"}]"}
let data2 = {"display:[{"counter":"A013","token":"003"}]"}
let mergedData = {"display": [...data1.display, ...data2.display]}
```

Comment: Your syntax isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can ise `Array.prototype.concat()`. Also your data1 and data2 values are not valid json. I updated those values

```js
let data1 = '{"display":[{"counter":"A023","token":"001"}]}';
let data2 = '{"display":[{"counter":"A013","token":"003"}]}';

data1 = JSON.parse(data1);
data2 = JSON.parse(data2);

data1.display = data1.display.concat(data2.display);
let output = JSON.stringify(data1)
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const obj1 = {};
const obj2 = {};

const objConcat = [...obj1, ...obj2];
```

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate on how this is the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and also put some properties in the objects to demonstrate what happens.

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.